# How can I get button events in the following code?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new to jQuery and I don't know how to get events when we press the button on the following code. Please help me.

```
<div class="key">
    <div class="buttonWrapper">    
        <span data-i18n="keypad.one" class="button i18n"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on Use `on`

Comment: Have you tried checking out the [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event on jQuerys API.

Comment: That's really basic @ptpdeepu, it's all in the basic documentation. Please read some:
https://api.jquery.com/click/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
To learn some basic:
http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/jquery

Comment: Thanks for your comments and help. Actually .click and .on events are working for buttons but not for the above code, so i had posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you want to capture what element you want to use, using `$()`. So in your case:

```
$(".button")
```

Then after you have gotten your element using `$()` you want to bind a event to it. In your case the `.click()` event:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
   // Insert what you want to happen when someone clicks the button here
});
```

To learn more about jQuery, I strongly recommend looking at their [API](http://api.jquery.com/). For more information about the `.click()` event click [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/). To learn more about events in general click [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Answer (score 0):

Use something like `click` function if it is statically loaded:

```
// Wait till the page is loaded and then do the following...
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Attach a click handler on the element with the class button.
  $(".button").click(function () {
    // The code to be executed when the button is clicked.
    alert("Hi");
  });
});
```

Or, if it is dynamic in nature, find a static parent and delegate the event:

```
// Wait till the page is loaded and then do the following...
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("body").on("click", ".button", function () {
    // The code to be executed when the button is clicked.
    alert("Hi");
  });
});
```

Please refer:

- [jQuery API `$.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [jQuery API `$.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)